# How to catch "null entry for parameter" error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I know there are loads of people getting this error, but most are using the built-in `id` functionality, of which I am not.  Beyond what I've read on this site, I need to present a friendly error rather than the built in yellow screen of death:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'productId'
>   of non-nullable type 'System.Int32'

My URL is...

> /myController/myView?person=789&productId=123

...where productId should actually contain an integer value.  Even though I check for it being `null` in the method, MVC throws the exception before the check is made.

Is it possible to *catch* this error and provide an Error view?

I know that I could set the variable type to be `Int32?` but that seems like a hack, as the method *does* require the value.

```
public ActionResult Show(string person, Int32 productId)
{
    if (productId== null) // exception occurs before this point, so this check fails
    {
        return View("Error", new ErrorViewModel { Summary = "No value provided" });
    }
// ....
}
```

Comment: Note that Int32 can never be null. So your check is invalid. You really need int? to make a null check. hence it's not really a hack it's necessary.

Comment: But is there any other way to check if the parameter value was provided in the URL?  The ActionLinks always create a value, but I'm trying to stop people messing around with the URL.

Comment: The error itself is the way to "stop people messing around with the URL". Trying to catch every possible thing a user might try to do is a fool's errand. If they mess with the URL, they get a 500. There's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisPratt that's actually the best answer for me...

Comment: I agree with Chris's answer. If you ever need to check if the value was provided the null check will do it, you can always just access the URL directly.

Comment: Were you ever able to find a way to catch this exception? I have a use case where I need to catch it at global level

Comment: @hitesh nullable integer is the only way. You can then also set a Required attribute on the model for auto validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is mixed up, this is how you should code your action:

```
public ActionResult Show(string person, Int32? productId)
{
  if (productId.HasValue == false ) // exception occurs before this point, so this check fails
  {
     return View("Error", new ErrorViewModel { Summary = "No value provided" });
  }
  // ....
}
```

Never will productId be null in the code you posted because no method signature could ever match a query string that had no `productId` in it.  Now with a nullable `productId` your code makes sense.